# TMS320VC5416 DSP firmware reversing

Tags: ida, disassembly, firmware

I have file with DSP firmware inside. Each chunk of code or data is preceded by header with format "page,offset,length".See below full list of headers:

---

page: 0000 offset: 0080 len: 0149
page: 0000 offset: 02c2 len: 033b
page: 0000 offset: 0639 len: 14d4
page: 0000 offset: 1bc6 len: 0053
page: 0000 offset: 4000 len: 0100
page: 0000 offset: 4220 len: 0009
page: 0000 offset: 4300 len: 00a1
page: 0000 offset: 4670 len: 0075
page: 0000 offset: 46f0 len: 00c4
page: 0000 offset: 47c0 len: 003e
page: 0000 offset: a210 len: 0009
page: 0000 offset: b0a4 len: 0030
page: 0000 offset: b1a8 len: 0039
page: 0000 offset: c000 len: 0200
page: 0000 offset: c9db len: 003f
page: 0000 offset: ca20 len: 013b
page: 0000 offset: cb60 len: 0034
page: 0000 offset: ce81 len: 00d1
page: 0000 offset: d000 len: 0100
page: 0000 offset: d200 len: 080e
page: 0002 offset: 9000 len: 339a
page: 0002 offset: f000 len: 08ab
page: 0003 offset: 8000 len: 435d

---

How can I implement memory paging addressing using standard ida pro facilities ?